# getting c++11 - compliant compiler

Tags: c++, macos, c++11, gnu, toolchain

This all seems like a colossal mess.
All I want is a compiler that implements C++11, so I can use `<chrono>`. But I'm so confused from the very beginning.

Currently, I build programs by invoking G++, but when I check the version via `$ g++ -v`, I get:

> gcc version 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build
>   2336.11.00)

What's going on? Am I using G++? GCC? LLVM? I don't even know. Are they the same thing?

So now I'm trying to build and download GCC 4.7 via [gnu.org](http://gcc.gnu.org/install/index.html), but I have no idea what any of the guides are talking about. I've never seen so many acronyms for things I dont know.

Why is this so complicated? What's with all those versions, with some of them only implementing some parts of C++11 and not others?

Comment: Looks like you're on a Mac. You can use [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/) to install a modern version of GCC. Compiling GCC from source is a little complicated so I think you'll want MacPorts.

Comment: @SethCarnegie thanks that! I used to click and install. Now it takes a following a book of command line commands to install anything. Like what.

Comment: Read [this section](http://guide.macports.org/#using) of the manual, and you can do `sudo port install gcc47` after installing MacPorts, and you'll have to find the command for using g++ 4.7 (I can't remember it). Also, I think Macs come with a modern Clang installed.

Comment: @SethCarnegie ya, but compiling with `clang` i get `fatal error: 'chrono' file not found`

Comment: Yeah, you have to tell it where your standard lib is and stuff or something, which I don't know how to do. You can check how XCode calls it via the options or something. But I avoid all that and just install GCC with that command I showed you.

Comment: You could always just use [Boost.Chrono](http://www.boost.org/libs/chrono/) instead...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Here's the situation on OS X.

There are two C++ compilers installed by default.

```
[5:49pm][wlynch@watermelon ~] g++ --version
i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-g++-4.2 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.11.00)

[5:49pm][wlynch@watermelon ~] clang++ --version
Apple LLVM version 4.2 (clang-425.0.24) (based on LLVM 3.2svn)
```

g++ is running llvm-gcc, which is the gcc frontend, and then the llvm backend.

clang++ is running clang, which is the clang frontend and then the llvm backend.

If you want a C++11 compiler on OS X without installing other packages, your only option is to use the clang compiler.

The flags necessary are:

```
clang++ -stdlib=libc++ -std=gnu++11
```

To describe the two flags I'm passing:

- `-stdlib=libc++` uses the libc++ standard library, instead of the gnu libstdc++. On OS X, the libc++ version has c++11 support. The gnu libstdc++ one does not.
- `-std=gnu++11` tells the compiler to support c++11 code features, like lambdas and enum class. You can also pass `-std=c++11`, which is similar, but does not enable some commonly expected gnu extensions.

**Update for OS X 10.9**: As of OS X Mavericks, both g++ and clang++ are actually using clang. The only difference, is that g++ will imply `-stdlib=libstdc++` and clang++ will imply `-stdlib=libc++`. So, on Mavericks, if you'd like to use C++11, you can follow the above advice, or just do:

```
clang++ -std=gnu++11
```

**Update for OS X 10.10**: As of OS X Yosemite, g++ is still clang in disguise. However, neither uses libstdc++ by default anymore. Both are now on libc++.

Comment: lol. Thank you!! So confusing, thank you for your explanation as well! So the llvm backend does the actual compiling regardless, with either gcc/clang doing the parsing? so the `-stdlib=libc++` tells the compiler where to find the libraries I want and the '-std=gnu++11` tells the compiler what version to follow? Why is gnu even involved in any of this?

Comment: [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10613126/what-are-the-differences-between-std-c11-and-std-gnu11) answers the differences between `-std=gnu++11` and `-std=c++11`. The short answer, is that gcc described some extensions to c++ that are often desirable. Clang optionally implements them.

Comment: You are also correct with your statement that the LLVM backend does the actually compiling regardless, and then gcc or clang is doing the parsing.

Comment: The final thing to note, is that GCC and libstdc++ do support C++11. However, Apple only includes older versions of the software (that don't support it) because of licensing fears (GPLv3).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have Xcode 4.6 and the latest command line tools. This is from the release notes:

```
Important: The LLVM GCC compiler does not include the latest Objective-C and 
C++11 features. Xcode 4.6 is the last major Xcode release which includes the 
LLVM GCC compiler and the GDB debugger. Please migrate your projects to use the 
LLVM compiler and LLDB debugger…
```

I think you want to use `c++` instead:

```
$ c++ -v
Apple LLVM version 4.2 (clang-425.0.24) (based on LLVM 3.2svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin12.2.0
Thread model: posix
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. what is `c++`?? Man I'm so confused. Are all these compilers the same? Different? Kind of different?

Comment: @ZacharyO'Keefe `c++` is an alias for `clang++`.

Comment: @SethCarnegie is `clang++` different from `clang`? Man. lol. what is `llvm-gcc`? is it llvm? gcc?

Comment: `clang++` is to `clang` as `g++` is to `gcc`; one is for C++, the other is for C. `llvm-gcc` is a version of GCC that targets the LLVM for code gen.

Answer (score 0):

@sharth: The situation changed on the Mac quite significantly since the release of XCode 5.0. clang/clang++ are the default C/C++ compilers. They correspond to the LLVM version 3.3 I believe, and this version of clang++ is [fully C++11-compliant](http://blog.llvm.org/2013/04/clang-support-for-c11-and-beyond.html). Note that `clang++ --version` will return a version number like "5.0.x" on the Mac but that refers to the XCode version.

I have been using the Apple clang++ in a C++11 project for months now and so far I have not seen any problems. There is absolutely no reason to use any other C++ compiler on the Mac just now :-)

The situation with GCC/G++ is not so rosy. The latest version of G++ (4.8.2) does implement most of the C++11 standard, however *the standard library is not compliant*! For instance, `std::regex` is not implemented in libstdc++, but you find this out only when you run your code and the regex constructors throw `std::regex_error` -s. (I found this out the hard way when trying to port the aforementioned little project to Linux.) The community believes full compliance will be achieved with the 4.9 release of G++. Until then you should use the Clang compilers on Linux as well.

I have no access to the latest Intel C++ compiler suite so have no idea how compliant `icpc` is.