# C++11 headers missing on Mac OS X 10.8.2 (MountainLion)

Tags: macos, c++11, osx-mountain-lion, macports

I'm new to Mac. I have some Linux and Windows C++11 source which uses Boost I'd like to build on this Mac.  Installed MacPort (should I instead be using Homebrew?) then successfully ran commands such as:

```
sudo port install cmake
sudo port install boost
sudo port install openssl
sudo port install gcc49
sudo port install gcc_select
sudo port install --set gcc mp-gcc49
```

CMake correctly finds Boost 1.57.0 and sets up the makefile.  But when I run `make`, it seems it cannot find normal C++11 headers such as "chrono":

```
In file included from ../src/test.cpp:10:
../src/test_private.hpp:33:10: fatal error: 'chrono' file not found
#include <chrono>
         ^
1 error generated.
```

Indeed, when I go looking for the C++ header files, I see some of them in `/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/` but newer files such as `chrono` and `thread` are missing.

Is there another package I need to install before I can compile C++11 source code on a Mac?

Comment: I'm 95% sure this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14656856/getting-c11-compliant-compiler/14657009#14657009

Comment: @BillLynch No, I'm already passing in the flag, and passing it in doesn't install the missing header files.

Comment: Could you show us the command that you are using to try and compile `src/test.cpp`?

Comment: @BillLynch was right.  The real C++11 headers are installed in `/usr/lib/c++/v1/` instead of where I was looking in `/usr/include/c++/`.  To get things to compile correctly, I had to add `-stdlib=libc++` to the compiler flags, not `-std=gnu++11` nor `-std=c++11`.

Comment: Upvoted to counter the moron's down vote.

Comment: If you're on >= 10.9 and are trying to use libraries from MacPorts, save yourself some time and compile with `clang++`. MacPorts' g++ will use libstdc++, but all libs in MacPorts use clang's libc++, so you'll end up mixing standard libraries. At best, it won't link, at worst, it'll crash at runtime and you'll have no idea why.

Answer (score 2):

Xcode, the Apple supplied compiler/tools, comes with two implementations of the std::lib:

1. gcc's libstdc++, version 4.2.
2. libc++

The first is very, very old, and does not support anything in C++11 such as `<chrono>`.  The second supports C++11 quite well, but can only be used with clang, not gcc.  clang comes with Xcode.

You will also need to install command line tools after you install Xcode:

```
xcode-select --install
```

Comment: Trying to run `sudo xcode-select --install` results in the following error message:  `xcode-select: Error: unknown command option '--install'.`

Comment: Sorry, perhaps there is info here that will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329243/xcode-4-4-and-later-install-command-line-tools