# OS X/Clang won't use c++11 headers

Tags: c++, macos, c++11, cmake, clang

system info: OS X 10.10.5, Clang = Apple LLVM version 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.53) (based on LLVM 3.6.0svn), cmake = 2.8.12.2

Suppose I have some simple file, main.cpp:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <vector>

#include <algorithm>

int main(void)
{
    std::vector<int> v{1, 2, 3, 4};

    int sum = std::accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), 0);

    printf("Sum = %d\n", sum);
    return 0;
 }
```

When I run "clang++ -stdlib=libc++ -std=c++11 main.cpp" I get error:

> main.cpp:11:20: error: no member named 'accumulate' in namespace 'std'
>      int sum = std::accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), 0);

When I look, using an IDE (Qt Creator), I see that the included header is /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/algorithm

when I look through my file system, I see that /usr/include/c++/4.2.1 exists with c++11 compliant headers.

---

Next, I use cmake to control larger builds (the above is just an example setup).

So here's a token CMakeLists.txt file for the above example:

```
project(c11Test)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE ON)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-stdlib=libc++ -std=gnu++11")

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)
```

Which, when I build, creates this output (excerpt):

> [100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/c11Test.dir/main.cpp.o
>   /usr/bin/c++    -stdlib=libc++ -std=gnu++11   -o
>   CMakeFiles/c11Test.dir/main.cpp.o -c /Users/username/c11Test/main.cpp
>   /Users/username/c11Test/main.cpp:11:20: error: no member named
>   'accumulate' in namespace 'std'
>       int sum = std::accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), 0);
>                 ~~~~~^ 1 error generated.

([whole output here](http://pastebin.com/bad9tPvm)):

I'm aware of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14656856/getting-c11-compliant-compiler/14657009#14657009), which seems to imply that all I need to do is just include these compiler flags. But that doesn't seem to work.

Furthermore, I probably need to build this on a variety of OS X computers at different versions, so I really wonder if there's a general solution I'm overlooking here?

Answer (score 17):

Another friend provided the answer:

In my bigger program (not here posted, obv.) Something had included `<numeric>` in some kind of hidden way. When I went to compile on OSX, it was no longer included. I had thought `<algorithm>` was the necessary component, but clearly it wasn't. So just my error.

Comment: If you're willing to possibly futz with experimental features you can turn on `-fmodules`, and this will tell you directly when you're trying to use a facility but haven't included the right header. For example here it would tell you you're using `accumulate` but have failed to `#include` the numeric header.

Comment: The reason I mention 'futzing' with experimental features is that I recall that at one point one of the libc++ headers required one change to correct a mistake that was made modularizing them. I think I have a script or something somewhere that applies the appropriate patch. I don't know if Apple has updated the version they ship with Xcode yet.