# unordered_multimap different behavior in gnu++11 and c++0x

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, mingw

I have the following program compiled at different compiler,and get different behavior ,

Source :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <unordered_map>

using namespace std ;

std::unordered_map<std::string,std::string> mymap;
std::unordered_multimap<std::string,std::string> mymultimap;
int main ()
{
    DoAddItem() ;

    std::cout << "mymap contains:";
    for ( auto it = mymap.begin(); it != mymap.end(); ++it )
        std::cout << " " << it->first << ":" << it->second;
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::cout << "============================================" << std::endl ;
    std::cout << "mymultimap contains:";
    for ( auto it2 = mymultimap.begin(); it2 != mymultimap.end(); ++it2 )
        std::cout << " " << it2->first << ":" << it2->second;
    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
} 

void  DoAddItem() 
{
    std::pair<std::string,std::string> mypair[100]; 
    int idx ;
    std::string s1  ;
    std::string s2  ;
    for(idx=0;idx<10;idx++)
    {
        s1 = string("key") + int2str(idx) ;
        s2 = string("val") + int2str(idx) ;
        mypair[idx] = {s1,s2} ;
        mymap.insert(mypair[idx]) ;
        mymultimap.insert(mypair[idx]) ;
    }//for 
    return ; 
}
```

Compiled in g++ 4.4.6 in RedHat Linux like :

```
g++  --std=c++0x unordered_map1.cpp -o unordered_map1.exe
```

will get the right answer for mymap and mymultimap ,  but in MinGw :
http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingwbuilds/?source=dlp

Compile it as the following :

```
g++ -std=gnu++11 unordered_map1.cpp -o unordered_map1.exe
```

This time , mymap still get the right answer , but mymultimap are all empty , 
the MinGw g++ version is

g++ (rev1, Built by MinGW-builds project) 4.8.1

I am interesting in c++11 so I download MinGw compiler in my winx ,
g++ 4.4.6 , my develope compiler , can not compile c++11 for test .

What I missed ? my goal is testing c++11 , Any suggestion is appreciated !!

Edit :

```
mymultimap.insert(mypair[idx]) ;   //won't work !!
mymultimap.insert(make_pair(s1,s2)) ; //This work !!
```

After I change my code to make_pair , it works in MinGw and print the right answer 
for mymultimap ....that is strange to me though ~~

Comment: there is no error message, OP states multimap is empty when using his code with MinGW

Comment: @barfatchen (1) With gnu++11 you also enable gnu extensions, see [What are the differences between -std=c++11 and -std=gnu++11?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10613126/341970) (2) At some point during the standardization procedure `pair` was broken, I don't remember the exact details. What you see might be related to that. Well, none of these things help you but let's hope someone can answer your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**BUG FILED** http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57619

This is not directly related to mingw. A test case compiled with [g++4.8](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=6be92fa7ffb5772f27fb4d1de1c5b85f-8cf037636069161efabc351c94329d4d) has the same problem. However, the same test case compiled with g++4.7.2 on ideone does not have this problem. This is a bug in g++4.8 and you should report it (or let me know and I will report it for you).

What is happening:

The call to `mymap.insert(mypair[0]);` is moving the string out of the `std::pair`. So, when `mymultimap.insert(mypair[0]);` is called, the strings have already been moved.

Here is a minimum test case:

```
std::unordered_map<std::string,std::string> mymap;
std::unordered_multimap<std::string,std::string> mymultimap;
int main ()
{
    std::pair<std::string,std::string> mypair[1]; 
    std::string s1 = std::string("key");
    std::string s2 = std::string("val");
    mypair[0] = {s1,s2};
    mymap.insert(mypair[0]);
    mymultimap.insert(mypair[0]);
    std::cout << "mymultimap contains:";
    for ( auto it2 = mymultimap.begin(); it2 != mymultimap.end(); ++it2 )
        std::cout << " " << it2->first << ":" << it2->second;
}
```

Comment: Thanks , If you could report this problem to related center , that would be great appreciated !! it is kind of you ~~