# C++ compiler: 'class std::vector<std::vector<char> >' has no member named 'emplace_back'

Tags: c++, vector, compiler-construction

I'm getting error from the compiler when coding C++. Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>     
#include <algorithm>   
#include <typeinfo>
#include <string>
#include <vector>


std::vector< std::vector<char> > p(std::vector<char> v)
{
    std::vector< std::vector<char> > result;

    std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());
    do
    {
        result.emplace_back(v);
    }
    while(std::next_permutation(v.begin(), v.end()));

    return result;
}
```

and here is my error:

[image]

Any idea what is causing this?

I'm using Codeblocks 12.11, Windows 7 and my compiler is GNU GCC Compiler

Thnx for the assist :)

**UPDATE:**

In case somebody bumps into the same problem, here is the solution (in Codeblocks 12.11):

Go to:   Settings --> Compiler --> Compiler settings --> Check the following checkboxes:

[image]

In addition to that remember to have a `main`-function in your code. Otherwise the compiler will give the following error:

[image]

The solution was given by the users who answered my post :)

Comment: 1. Does the GCC version (actually standard library version) support C++11? 2. If yes, are you passing the appropriate flag to GCC (something like `-std=c++11` or `-std=c++0x`)?

Comment: +1 I think it does not as @Jefffrey stated. How can I fix this in Codeblocks?

Comment: I was not able to check both of the boxes, but the code seems to be working by checking one of the two. Can anyone explain?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Your compiler is not supporting C++11. The `emplace_back` member function of `std::vector<T>` has been added since C++11, as [you can see](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back).

Depending on your compiler version, you probably just need some flags to tell the compiler to turn on C++11 features. You can do that on GCC and Clang with:

```
-std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++
```

Otherwise you might need to update your compiler version to a more recent one.

Comment: I had to use `-std=gnu++14` ([see also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10613126/what-are-the-differences-between-std-c11-and-std-gnu11)). Although I could only reproduce the issue with [rapidjson](https://github.com/Tencent/rapidjson).