# CImg compilation errors in CodeBlocks 17.12

Tags: c++, mingw, codeblocks, libraries, cimg

I'm trying to work with CImg library, but I constantly get compilation errors, so I'm not able to find out if my programs would use this library correctly.
I've started with the default code just for testing:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "CImg.h"
using namespace std;
int main()
{
cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
return 0;
}
```

After compiling, I get the following errors:

> 6205|error: '_fileno' was not declared in this scope
>
> In function 'FILE* cimg_library::cimg::win_fopen(const char*, const char*)':
>
> |59832|error: '_wfopen' was not declared in this scope|

How can I get this to work properly? I use gnu++11 compiler (as it was said in [Compiling CImg with c++0x and MingW](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22081825/compiling-cimg-with-c0x-and-mingw) ) but it still does not work.

Comment: Done, but I still get scope error for `_fileno`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compiling CImg with c++0x and MingW](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22081825/compiling-cimg-with-c0x-and-mingw)

Comment: Please show the commands used to compile.

Comment: Try adding `#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L` as the very first line of your code.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Comment: @MarkSetchell no, I changed the IDE

Comment: If you need to troubleshot the problem under Code::Blocks, you have to show use the full build log, see here: [1 Q: How do I troubleshoot a compiler problem?](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php/FAQ-Compiling_(errors)#Q:_How_do_I_troubleshoot_a_compiler_problem.3F)