# warning: decomposition declaration only available with -std=c++1z or -std=gnu++1

Tags: c++, stl

I've got this warning:

```
warning: decomposition declaration only available with -std=c++1z or -std=gnu++1
```

for this code:

```
#include<algorithm>
#include<vector>

int main(){
    std::vector<int> vect{ 10, 20, 30 };
    const auto [min, max] = std::minmax_element(vect.begin(), vect.end());

    return 0;
}
```

what does *decomposition declaration* in this context means?

Comment: Well, just add that to your compiler flags as suggested? It means your code uses a feature, which is only available in a different (newer) standard than the compilers default.

Comment: Namely, you use the so-called [structured binding declaration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding) which was added to C++ by the C++17 standard. This was referred to as C++1z before its official publication. Additionally, you may be interested in this question: [What are the differences between -std=c++11 and -std=gnu++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10613126/580083) plus this article: [History of C++](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/history).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> what does it mean?

The warning means that you've used syntax / language feature that was introduced to the language in C++17 standard (whose working title was C++1z), but you are compiling for an older standard version.

> what does decomposition declaration in this context means?

"Decomposition declaration" is another name for [*structured bindings*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding) which is the new(ish) language feature that is being used on the line:

> ```
> const auto [min, max] = std::minmax_element(vect.begin(), vect.end());
> ```

The simplified grammar of structured bindings (i.e. decomposition declarations) is:

```
auto [ identifier-list ] = expression ;
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but apparently my question is misleading: I want to know what decomposition declaration in this context meant, not that what's follow. I've update the question.