# Is g++ different than g++ -std=c++14 when the default standard is 201402L (c++14)?

Tags: gcc, g++, c++14, precompiled-headers, gcc10

I was trying to make use of precompiled headers to speed up compilation following this link: https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/53909

I observed that pre-compilation of headers and subsequent compilation of .cpp programs have to be done using the same g++ flags for the speed-up to work, which makes sense. However, explicitly setting the c++ standard to the default one did not work. So, neither of pre-compilation using `g++ stdc++.h` and subsequent `g++ -std=c++14 program.cpp`, nor, `g++ -std=c++14` and `g++ program.cpp` worked.

This didn't make sense to me as I knew that my compiler, x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++.exe (gcc version 10.2.0), by default, conforms to 201402L (c++14) standard, which I figured using `g++ -dM -E -x c++ /dev/null | fgrep __cplusplus`, and getting the following response:

```
#define __cplusplus 201402L
```

So, my question is, what is the difference between g++ and g++ -std=c++14 when g++, by default, adheres to 201402L? Also, is it significant enough for me to specifically opt for either one of them ?

Comment: It may create a record (like a hash sum) of all the options used and put that inside the precompiled header and if it doesn't match when you recompile, it'll recreate the precompiled header.

Comment: On a second thought. `g++` doesn't default to `-std=c++<something>`. Afaik, it defaults to `-std=gnu++<something>`. Check if it makes the same choice if you compile with and without `-std=gnu++14`

Comment: Yes, both g++ -std=gnu++14 and g++ -std=gnu++1y (although deprecated) works, ie, the precompiled headers speed up all subsequent compilations using only g++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GCC doesn't compile with `-std=c++14` by default. The description of the `-std` flag from the [GCC man pages](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/gcc.1.html) (for version 9.3.0) says

> `-std=` Determine the language standard.   This option is currently only supported when compiling C or C++.
>
> The compiler can accept several base standards, such as c90 or c++98, and GNU dialects of those standards, such as gnu90 or gnu++98. When a base standard is specified, the compiler accepts all programs following that standard plus those using GNU extensions that do not contradict it.
> . . . 
> A value for this option must be provided; possible values are
>
> . . .
>
> c++14
> c++1y
>     The 2014 ISO C++ standard plus amendments.  The name c++1y is deprecated.
>
>  
> gnu++14 
> gnu++1y
>     GNU dialect of -std=c++14.  **This is the default for C++ code.**  The name gnu++1y is deprecated.
> . . .

Emphasis mine. The current default is `-std=gnu++14`, which targets the C++14 standard while also enabling [GNU extensions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C_002b_002b-Extensions.html) to the C++ language. The distinction between the `-std=c++XX` flags and the `-std=gnu++XX` flags is explained further in [What are the differences between -std=c++11 and -std=gnu++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10613126/what-are-the-differences-between-std-c11-and-std-gnu11).

Comment: Thanks. Confirmed that g++ and g++ -std=gnu++14 amounted to the same thing.